# How do I save order of *.launch favorites in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I have an eclipse project stored in subversion that contains `*.launch` files.  The problem is each time someone imports the project, the ordering of the external tools corresponding to the `*.launch` files changes.  Where is the ordering stored?  Is it possible to store that ordering with the project in subversion so that on each import, the ordering is the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the display order of the `*.launch` files aren't random, but a derivative of alphabetically.

Example:

- FixClassPathForTesting
- Manual systemTest classpath
- RunMeFirst
- BAR-FullDeploy
- BAR-Restart
- FOO-FullDeploy
- FOO-Restart

I don't know the rules, but it seems to group files if they have a common prefix and show those after non-prefixed files. (Notice "FixClassPathForTesting" is before "BAR-*")

There isn't a way to specify the desired ordering, but fiddling with the name of each `*.launch` file can result in the desired order.